# When does Illyana Rasputin train with Doctor Strange?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Issue 7 of [Uncanny X-Men: Volume 3](http://marvel.wikia.com/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_3) ends with

> Illyana teleporting the X-Men out of Limbo into a field somewhere, but she is not with them.

Illyana approaches Doctor Strange,

> apparently in the past. She asks for him to train her.

Issue 8 picks up and Illyana is with the team and no mention is made of what happened between these two issues.

I've read all of the issues available on Marvel Unlimited and checked the synopses of the remaining existing issues and there is no indication that these events have been addressed in the Uncanny X-Men issues.

**Is there anywhere that explains what happened between Illyana and Dr. Strange during this time frame?**

Comment: I believe that's still to be revealed as it happened in the past for Doc Strange... if that was even our Doc Strange.  Remember Limbo allows Illyana access to multiple dimensions via her discs, as explained in the Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 by Claremont and Magik limited series ( here's a synopses of that ltd series: http://uncannyxmen.net/db/issues/showfaq.asp?fldAuto=78 )

Comment: From what I remember, in All-new X-men there is at least one scene of Illyana training with Dr. Strange in the past and the dialogue seems to indicate that it's a regular thing.

Answer (score 1):

Since Illyana is the Sorceress Supreme of Limbo, it seems to make sense for her to want to train with the Sorcerer Supreme of Dr. Strange's ability and reputation. My guess (although I've yet to see it confirmed in print) is that she trained with him to improve her skills and control over her magik.

Comment: Presumably her training specifically relates to controlling her Darkchilde persona which we saw in earlier issues in the fight against Dormammu (if I remember correctly)